# Karate - Matching 2 JSON objects for values with few objects with missing keys

Tags: karate

I have 2 json as follows:

```
* def first = [{"code":"00","name":"A","iconUrl":"https:env1.test.png"}, {"code":"01","name":"B"}, {"code":"03","name":"C","iconUrl":"https:env1.test.png"}, {"code":"02","name":"D"}]

* def second = [{"iconUrl":"https:env2.test.png", "code":"00","name":"A"}, {"code":"01","name":"B"}, {"iconUrl":"https:env2.test.png", "code":"03","name":"C"}, {"code":"02","name":"D"}]
```

I want to compare the 2 json objects. All the objects dont have iconUrl and those which have contains difference of env in the url.

I tried the following :

```
* def first = [{"code":"00","name":"A","iconUrl":"https:env1.test.png"}, {"code":"01","name":"B"}, {"code":"03","name":"C","iconUrl":"https:env1.test.png"}, {"code":"02","name":"D"}]
    * def second = [{"iconUrl":"https:env2.test.png", "code":"00","name":"A"}, {"code":"01","name":"B"}, {"iconUrl":"https:env2.test.png", "code":"03","name":"C"}, {"code":"02","name":"D"}]
    * def size = second.length
    And print "     size: ", size
    * def fun = function(i){ if (second[i].iconUrl != '#null') second[i].iconUrl = '#string'}
    * def foo = karate.repeat(size, fun)
    * match first contains second
```

My test is failing due to the array object not containing the iconUrl. How do i add another condition for the objects not containing the iconUrl?

Comment: The link you mentioned is for the pdf reporting. I am afraid that it solves my issue

Comment: the answer is that there is no ready-made PDF reporting. what do you expect me to do then ? you decide :)

Comment: I marked that as accepted. :) But i was expecting the workaround for the current problem though :) Please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709878/karate-matching-2-json-objects-for-values-with-few-objects-with-missing-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def fun = function(x){ if (x.iconUrl) x.iconUrl = x.iconUrl.replace('env2', 'env1'); return x }
* def secondFixed = karate.map(second, fun)
* match first == secondFixed
```

Comment: Really appreciate your quick responses. Thanks much :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can we not test it with the way i was doing and could implement another condition for the objects not containing the iconUrl?

Comment: @user1873274 you can. but `map()` is better for transformations. and `forEach()` is better than manually looping n times